# org.jruby.exceptions.NameError: (NameError) cannot load Java class org.logstash.util.JavaVersion

Tags: java, logstash, jruby

I am trying to run `logstash 7.16.3` with `jruby v9.2.20.1`.

**Getting this error :**

```
org.jruby.exceptions.NameError: (NameError) cannot load Java class org.logstash.util.JavaVersion
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaClass.for_name(org/jruby/javasupport/JavaClass.java:292)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaClass.for_name(org/jruby/javasupport/JavaClass.java:288)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaUtilities.get_proxy_class(org/jruby/javasupport/JavaUtilities.java:39)
    at RUBY.java_import(uri:classloader:/jruby/java/core_ext/object.rb:44)
    at org.jruby.RubyArray.map(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2589)
    at RUBY.java_import(uri:classloader:/jruby/java/core_ext/object.rb:37)
    at RUBY.<main>(/platform/bin/explorer230p7/lib/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:17)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:974)
    at platform.bin.explorer230p7.lib.logstash.lib.bootstrap.environment.<main>(/platform/bin/explorer230p7/lib/logstash/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:92)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.logstash.util.JavaVersion
```

I checked the zip of `logstash` and it contains the class `JavaVersion.java`.
Why is it throwing `classNotFound` exception then?